# Waiting for dependencies when running in parallel

Tags: doit

When running doit with `-n` option, the task doesn't seem to wait for the `file_dep` to be created by other sub-tasks. Here is a simple code that tries to show the issue:

```py
def task_pexample():

    yield {
        "name":"test1",
        "actions": ["sleep 5", "touch tmp.txt"],
        "targets":["tmp.txt"]
    }

    yield {
        "name":"test2",
        "file_dep":["tmp.txt"],
        "targets":["tmp2.txt"],
        "actions": ["cp tmp.txt tmp2.txt"],
    }
```

`doit -s pexample` runs without a problem. However when running `doit -n 2 -s pexample`, it starts the second subtask right away, without waiting for the first one to complete. This then generates an error since the file doesn't exist.

My question is whether `doit` does or doesn't look for such dependencies in subtask when running in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `doit` looks for dependencies when executing in parallel.

The problem with your example is that you are using the `-s/--single` command line option. `-s` instructs `doit` to execute the specified task ignoring the dependencies.

`-s` is supposed to be used on special occasions while developing your task's code, not be used during standard execution.

Comment: indeed simply running `doit -n 2 pexample` actually works. Thank you! Can you explain what `-s` does exactly?